# Interpolate values of a wind time series using matlab

Tags: matlab, time, time-series, series, interpolation

I have a data set in matlab with several variables (pressure, O2 levels, ect) that correspond to one time series.

I would like to add wind data to the dataset, but this time series has a different time scale. How can I interpolate this wind data onto my current time series? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have a much higher chance of getting a useful answer if you create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's quite difficult to answer the question as it stands. For example, is one on a linear scale and the other a log scale? You don't state that. Please update your question.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, you should accept it. Otherwise, you should comment as to why it is not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can interpolate your data by using **interp1**:

```
% // Original data
times = 0:6:20;
values = rand(1,length(times));

% Interpolated data
interp_times = 0:2:20; 
interp_values = interp1(times,values,interp_times)
```

The vector *interp_times* defines for wich times a interpolation will be performed. The vector can be adjusted as needed.

The result would look like:
[image]